# Java7 Fork-Join или ExecutorService для многопоточного сервера?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, многопоточность, framework

Задача Java сервера - принимать с клиентов запроса и поиск с сортировкой данных в коллекции значений для дальнейшей отправки.

Есть ExecutorService версия многопоточной работы с клиентскими запросами (ее можно улучшить?):

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try (Socket socket = new ServerSocket(init()).accept();
            BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());) { 
                outToClient.write(autocomplete(fromClient.readLine()).getBytes("US-ASCII"));
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                service.shutdown(); 
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Для сравнения, стандартные потоки:

```
try (Socket socket = new ServerSocket(getPort()).accept()) {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try (BufferedReader getString = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
                    DataOutputStream sendString = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());) { 
                        sendString.write(autocomplete(getString.readLine()).getBytes("US-ASCII"));
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
} catch (IOException ex) { 
    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Или лучше использовать **ForkJoinPool**...? не будет ли в *Java7* функциональность ForkJoinPool излишней по сравнению с **ExecutorService**? Или, наоборот будет лучше работать с тысячами потоков обработки и отправки по Socket, учитывая переиспользование уже созданных потоков?

Comment: И что, это работает? Подозрение вызывает создание многих экземпляров ServerSocket. По моему разумению, создание уже второго экземпляра должно вызвать ошибку типа Address already in use.

Comment: @rfq
Спасибо! Нет, не совсем... сейчас socket = new ServerSocket(8).accept() вызывает исключение "java.net.BindException: Отказано в доступе".

Comment: Отказано в доступе или permission denied? возможная причина - порты с номерами < 1024 позволено открывать только под root'ом.